# DB2: should I decode fetched data with utf8, regardless of the database code set?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, db2, dbi

Is utf-8 the correct encoding for decoding data retrieved from a DB2 database, regardless of the database's code set?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
my ( $db, $dbh, $sth, $value );
my $table = 'mytablename';
my $user = 'user';
my $password = 'passwd';
my $char = "\x{20ac}"; # €

# ISODB code set = ISO885915
$db = 'ISODB';
$dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:DB2:$db", $user, $password ) or die DBI->errstr;
$dbh->do( "DROP TABLE $table" );
$dbh->do( "CREATE TABLE $table (Name VARCHAR(32))" );
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table (Name) VALUES(?)" );
$sth->execute( $char );
( $value ) = $dbh->selectrow_array( "SELECT Name FROM $table" );
printf "%v02X\n", $value;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect();

# UTFDB code set = utf-8
$db = 'UTFDB';
$dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:DB2:$db", $user, $password ) or die DBI->errstr;
$dbh->do( "DROP TABLE $table" );
$dbh->do( "CREATE TABLE $table (Name VARCHAR(32))" );
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table (Name) VALUES(?)" );
$sth->execute( $char );
( $value ) = $dbh->selectrow_array( "SELECT Name FROM $table" );
printf "%v02X\n", $value;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

```
# E2.82.AC
# E2.82.AC
```

Comment: Have you understood the concept of application-codepage?

Comment: @mao, Is that a DB2 concept? Perl doesn't have an "application codepage".

Comment: @sid_com, You still have a situation where you could have two bugs that cancel each other out. I don't think so, but I'm not sure. Your test would be more reliable if you generate the correct character using a db function.

Comment: @ikegami Yes. Any Db2 app, regardless of programming language, has an application-codepage, whether the programmer knows it or not. The ODBC driver transparently converts between the app-codepage and db-codepage and encoding. The operating-system and regional settings implicitly determine the app-codepage. The environment variable DB2CODEPAGE determines the app-codepage explicitly.

Comment: @ikegami How could I generate a character with a db function?

Comment: @mao Now I have learned that there is a database code page and an application code page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding used by DBD::DB2 is determined [from the environment](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-derivation-code-page-values).

You can query the encoding of the database and the encoding of the connection using `$dbh->get_info`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI qw( );

use constant {
   SQL_DATABASE_CODEPAGE    => 2519,
   SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE => 2520,
};

{
   my $dbh = ...;

   printf( "SQL_DATABASE_CODEPAGE:    %s\n", $dbh->get_info( SQL_DATABASE_CODEPAGE    ) );
   printf( "SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE: %s\n", $dbh->get_info( SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE ) );

   my $val = $dbh->selectrow_array( "SELECT * FROM ( VALUES( CHR( 201 ) ) )" );
   printf( "%v02X\n", $val );
}
```

```
$ enctest
SQL_DATABASE_CODEPAGE:    819
SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE: 819   # ISO-8859-1
C9

$ DB2CODEPAGE=1208 enctest
SQL_DATABASE_CODEPAGE:    819
SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE: 1208  # UTF-8
C3.E9
```

You should either query the `SQL_APPLICATION_CODEPAGE`, or ensure that a known code page is used.